# Book about a white mother who kills her black son (with her other white son)

Tags: identification-request, race-issues

I remember reading this perhaps during elementary school.

While this wasn't the entire plot of the book, one of its major points was a mother who slept with a black man and had a black son. She and her other (white) son bully and starve the black boy sometimes, and she's ashamed of him.

Near the end of the book, the town finds the black son's remains days after he dies, after which they go and kill the mother and white son.

Comment: Do you remember anything else from the plot? When were you in elementary school? What perspective was it written from? Any details you can add will be useful.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Please take our [tour]! In order to increase the chance of getting an identification, please read the [info page](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) for [tag:identification-request] questions. Can you supply any of the suggested information listed on that page? E.g., when and where did you read the book? What do you remember about the book's physical attributes—cover, size, etc? Was it a children's book or one for young adults? Such details will help narrow down the possibilities. Thanks!

Comment: To add to the above comments, when and where did the story take place?